# Invalid Identifier error in Oracle.

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am executing this query i SQL server and it is working fine but when I try to execute it in oracle, then it generates an error that invalid identifier "IS NULL". Can anyone translate this query in oracle supported query? Please help me. Thank you

```
       SELECT 
       RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME,
       RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME, RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE ,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat AS "Rank",
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('29','721') THEN '0.25' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('921','301','30','722','601','581') THEN '0.50' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('2','1', '4') THEN '0.70' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MIN(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  IN ('1','2') then '0' else '1' END) * 
                     MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  IN ('4') then '0.20' else '0' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('31','723') THEN '0.75' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC = '861' THEN '0.80' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('17','302','16') THEN '0.85' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') *
       isnull(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN ('3','7') THEN '0.90' ELSE '1' END),'0'),'1') AS "FTE VALUE"

     FROM RM_LIVE.EMPBASE,
     RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE,
     RM_LIVE.CRWBASE,
     RM_LIVE.EMPNAME,
     RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC,
     RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC,RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT
       where RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
        AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDCRWBASE = RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.IDCRWBASE
         AND RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.IDEMPNO 
          AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC =RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  
           AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDEMPNO =RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
            AND  RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDEMPNO=RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO 
             AND  RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.IDCRWCAT = RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDCRWCAT
              AND RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat IN ('CP','FO','CM','MC')
               AND RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE <> 'XYZ'
                AND RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN  
                ('921','2' ,'1','301','17','4','3','7','302' ,'861','31',
                 '723','30','722 ','29 ','721','16','601','581')  
                  AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                   AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
                    AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                     AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
                      AND RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FROMDATE <=SYSDATE
                       AND RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                        AND RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
                        AND TRUNC(RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.STARTDATE) <=    TO_DATE('01/JAN/2013','dd/mon/yyyy')
                        AND TRUNC(RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.ENDDATE) > =  TO_DATE('01/JAN/2013','dd/mon/yyyy')
  GROUP BY RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME,
       RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME, RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat;
```

Comment: Why do you have numbers enclosed in single quotes, making them string literals instead of actual numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`isNULL` is not defined in oracle try `NVL` instead

Comment: I was wondering - was there a reason you rolled back my edit? Nothing was changed, but the punctuation and capitalization were improved, and `ISNULL` and `NVL` (which *are* function names) were wrapped in code blocks, as they should be. I ask because another one of your edits — where code blocks are used inappropriately — is the subject of a [Meta Stack Overflow question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322098/why-is-this-a-terrible-edit-suggest); I'm wondering if there's some confusion as to the meaning of backticks (\`) in Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: i just wanted to see if the rollback works or not, i have made the suggested edits, thanks for the suggested edit